# Use PHP to output specific code for every 3rd record in a record set

Tags: php, loops

At the moment I have a page that outputs a bunch of records held for each person on the database. So for every person that is displayed on this page, all their details are also shown.

What I am now trying to do is format this data correctly, so that after every 3rd or 4th person some HTML code is inserted to break the data up and make it easier to read, such as a grey bar stating what the data is for. I don't know though how I could do this?

**EDIT**
I've added the code that has been suggested to my code, which now looks like this:

```
    <div class="content">
         <?php $i=0; ?>
            <?php foreach ($members as $members) { ?>
            <div class="repblock">

            </div>              
        <?php
            if (($i%4) == 0) { ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="page" style="page-break-before: always;">
                <div class="content">
        <?php   }
         $i++; } ?>
    </div>
```

And the code suggested works to a point. What's happening is that the first member is displayed on its own, then four records are displayed in a group, and then it continues to display the remaining in groups of four until the records are exhausted, like this:

> Member Record 1
>   ----------------
>  Member Record 2
>  Member Record 3
>  Member Record 4
>  Member Record 5 
>   ---------------- 
>  Member Record 6 
>  Member Record 7 
>  Member Record 8
>  Member Record 9 
>   ---------------- 
>  Member Record 10 
>  Member Record 11

Why is it displaying just one record on it's own at the beginning, then grouping the records correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very simple.

You have to keep a counter, increment it for every person, whenever it crosses 3 or 4, output seperator and reset counter.

something like:

```
$i = 0;
// for loop here
if(($i = $i%3) == 0){
    echo '<hr />';
}
$i++;
// end for loop
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this has helped me. But it's created a new problem, which I've added to the question.

Comment: @mickburkejnr start from `$i=1;` instead of 0.

Answer (score 3):

Without a code-sample, I'm going to assume you're using a standard `for` loop to iterate through your data. With this, you can use the modulus operator, `%`, to check which number you're on:

```
$numRecords = count($yourData);
for ($i = 0; $i < $numRecords; $i++) {
    if (($i > 0) && (($i % 3) == 0)) {
        // display a <br />, <hr />, whatever
    }

    // display stuff
}
```

If you're using a `foreach` loop, you can keep a separate counter outside of it and check it the same way:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($yourData as $singleRecord) {
    if ((++$i % 3) == 0) {
        // display a <br />, <hr />, whatever
    }

    // display stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the modulus operator to determine which index is every third.

```
if ($index % 3 == 0) {
    // Every third.
}
```